# samba on vmware, debian squeeze

Tags: debian, samba, vmware-player

I've installed debian squeeze as a virtual machine. I've installed and configured samba and i can't seem to connect from my windows client through explorer \ipaddr gives an error so does \ipaddr\share . I tried running samba client from the command line using

> smbclient -L \localhost -U root

this has a positive result, so it seems like i can't connect from a remote location. Might there be a conflict with vmare player, does vmware player run samba as well?
Do i need to add something specific to the config to get it working in a virtual environment?

Hope this makes any sense

----- EDIT

```
root@debian:/etc/samba# smbclient -L \192.168.0.128 -U root
Enter root's password:
Domain=[PRIVATEGAMERS] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.5.6]

        Sharename       Type      Comment
        ---------       ----      -------
        print$          Disk      Printer Drivers
        www             Disk
        IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (debian server)
        root            Disk      Home Directories
Domain=[PRIVATEGAMERS] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.5.6]

        Server               Comment
        ---------            -------
        DEBIAN               debian server

        Workgroup            Master
        ---------            -------
        PRIVATEGAMERS
```

SMB config

```
#
# Sample configuration file for the Samba suite for Debian GNU/Linux.
#
#
# This is the main Samba configuration file. You should read the
# smb.conf(5) manual page in order to understand the options listed
# here. Samba has a huge number of configurable options most of which 
# are not shown in this example
#
# Some options that are often worth tuning have been included as
# commented-out examples in this file.
#  - When such options are commented with ";", the proposed setting
#    differs from the default Samba behaviour
#  - When commented with "#", the proposed setting is the default
#    behaviour of Samba but the option is considered important
#    enough to be mentioned here
#
# NOTE: Whenever you modify this file you should run the command
# "testparm" to check that you have not made any basic syntactic 
# errors. 
# A well-established practice is to name the original file
# "smb.conf.master" and create the "real" config file with
# testparm -s smb.conf.master >smb.conf
# This minimizes the size of the really used smb.conf file
# which, according to the Samba Team, impacts performance
# However, use this with caution if your smb.conf file contains nested
# "include" statements. See Debian bug #483187 for a case
# where using a master file is not a good idea.
#

#======================= Global Settings =======================

[global]    public = yes
#   socket address = 192.168.0.128

## Browsing/Identification ###

# Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of    workgroup = PRIVATEGAMERS

# server string is the equivalent of the NT Description field    server string = %h server

# Windows Internet Name Serving Support Section:
# WINS Support - Tells the NMBD component of Samba to enable its WINS Server
#   wins support = no

# WINS Server - Tells the NMBD components of Samba to be a WINS Client
# Note: Samba can be either a WINS Server, or a WINS Client, but NOT both ;   wins server = w.x.y.z

# This will prevent nmbd to search for NetBIOS names through DNS.    dns proxy = no

# What naming service and in what order should we use to resolve host names
# to IP addresses ;   name resolve order = lmhosts host wins bcast

#### Networking ####

# The specific set of interfaces / networks to bind to
# This can be either the interface name or an IP address/netmask;
# interface names are normally preferred
#   interfaces =  255.255.255.0 eth0

# Only bind to the named interfaces and/or networks; you must use the
# 'interfaces' option above to use this.
# It is recommended that you enable this feature if your Samba machine is
# not protected by a firewall or is a firewall itself.  However, this
# option cannot handle dynamic or non-broadcast interfaces correctly.
#   bind interfaces only = yes


#### Debugging/Accounting ####

# This tells Samba to use a separate log file for each machine
# that connects    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m

# Cap the size of the individual log files (in KiB).    max log size = 1000

# If you want Samba to only log through syslog then set the following
# parameter to 'yes'.
#   syslog only = no

# We want Samba to log a minimum amount of information to syslog. Everything
# should go to /var/log/samba/log.{smbd,nmbd} instead. If you want to log
# through syslog you should set the following parameter to something higher.    syslog = 0

# Do something sensible when Samba crashes: mail the admin a backtrace    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d


####### Authentication #######

# "security = user" is always a good idea. This will require a Unix account
# in this server for every user accessing the server. See
# /usr/share/doc/samba-doc/htmldocs/Samba3-HOWTO/ServerType.html
# in the samba-doc package for details.
#   security = user

# You may wish to use password encryption.  See the section on
# 'encrypt passwords' in the smb.conf(5) manpage before enabling.   encrypt passwords = true

# If you are using encrypted passwords, Samba will need to know what
# password database type you are using.      passdb backend = tdbsam

   obey pam restrictions = yes

# This boolean parameter controls whether Samba attempts to sync the Unix
# password with the SMB password when the encrypted SMB password in the
# passdb is changed.    unix password sync = yes

# For Unix password sync to work on a Debian GNU/Linux system, the following
# parameters must be set (thanks to Ian Kahan <<kahan@informatik.tu-muenchen.de> for
# sending the correct chat script for the passwd program in Debian Sarge).   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u    passwd chat =
*Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .

# This boolean controls whether PAM will be used for password changes
# when requested by an SMB client instead of the program listed in
# 'passwd program'. The default is 'no'.    pam password change = yes

########## Domains ###########

# Is this machine able to authenticate users. Both PDC and BDC
# must have this setting enabled. If you are the BDC you must
# change the 'domain master' setting to no
# ;   domain logons = yes
#
# The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
# It specifies the location of the user's profile directory
# from the client point of view)
# The following required a [profiles] share to be setup on the
# samba server (see below) ;   logon path = \\%N\profiles\%U
# Another common choice is storing the profile in the user's home directory
# (this is Samba's default)
#   logon path = \\%N\%U\profile

# The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
# It specifies the location of a user's home directory (from the client
# point of view) ;   logon drive = H:
#   logon home = \\%N\%U

# The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
# It specifies the script to run during logon. The script must be stored
# in the [netlogon] share
# NOTE: Must be store in 'DOS' file format convention ;   logon script = logon.cmd

# This allows Unix users to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
# RPC pipe.  The example command creates a user account with a disabled Unix
# password; please adapt to your needs ; add user script = /usr/sbin/adduser
--quiet --disabled-password --gecos "" %u

# This allows machine accounts to be created on the domain controller via the 
# SAMR RPC pipe.  
# The following assumes a "machines" group exists on the system ; add machine script  = /usr/sbin/useradd -g machines -c "%u machine account" -d /var/lib/samba -s /bin/false %u

# This allows Unix groups to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
# RPC pipe.   ; add group script = /usr/sbin/addgroup --force-badname %g

########## Printing ##########

# If you want to automatically load your printer list rather
# than setting them up individually then you'll need this
#   load printers = yes

# lpr(ng) printing. You may wish to override the location of the
# printcap file ;   printing = bsd ;   printcap name = /etc/printcap

# CUPS printing.  See also the cupsaddsmb(8) manpage in the
# cupsys-client package. ;   printing = cups ;   printcap name = cups

############ Misc ############

# Using the following line enables you to customise your configuration
# on a per machine basis. The %m gets replaced with the netbios name
# of the machine that is connecting ;   include = /home/samba/etc/smb.conf.%m

# Most people will find that this option gives better performance.
# See smb.conf(5) and /usr/share/doc/samba-doc/htmldocs/Samba3-HOWTO/speed.html
# for details
# You may want to add the following on a Linux system:
#         SO_RCVBUF=8192 SO_SNDBUF=8192
#   socket options = TCP_NODELAY

# The following parameter is useful only if you have the linpopup package
# installed. The samba maintainer and the linpopup maintainer are
# working to ease installation and configuration of linpopup and samba. ; message command = /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/linpopup "%f" "%m" %s; rm %s' &

# Domain Master specifies Samba to be the Domain Master Browser. If this
# machine will be configured as a BDC (a secondary logon server), you
# must set this to 'no'; otherwise, the default behavior is recommended.
#   domain master = auto

# Some defaults for winbind (make sure you're not using the ranges
# for something else.) ;   idmap uid = 10000-20000 ;   idmap gid = 10000-20000 ;   template shell = /bin/bash

# The following was the default behaviour in sarge,
# but samba upstream reverted the default because it might induce
# performance issues in large organizations.
# See Debian bug #368251 for some of the consequences of *not*
# having this setting and smb.conf(5) for details. ;   winbind enum groups = yes ;   winbind enum users = yes

# Setup usershare options to enable non-root users to share folders
# with the net usershare command.

# Maximum number of usershare. 0 (default) means that usershare is disabled. ;   usershare max shares = 100

#======================= Share Definitions =======================

[homes]    comment = Home Directories  browseable = no

# By default, the home directories are exported read-only. Change the
# next parameter to 'no' if you want to be able to write to them.    read only = yes

# File creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create files with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to
0775.    create mask = 0700

# Directory creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create dirs. with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to
0775.    directory mask = 0700

# By default, \\server\username shares can be connected to by anyone
# with access to the samba server.
# The following parameter makes sure that only "username" can connect
# to \\server\username
# This might need tweaking when using external authentication schemes    valid users = %S

# Un-comment the following and create the netlogon directory for Domain Logons
# (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.) ;[netlogon] ;   comment = Network Logon Service ;   path = /home/samba/netlogon ;   guest ok = yes ;   read only = yes

# Un-comment the following and create the profiles directory to store
# users profiles (see the "logon path" option above)
# (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
# The path below should be writable by all users so that their
# profile directory may be created the first time they log on ;[profiles] ;   comment = Users profiles ;   path = /home/samba/profiles ;   guest ok = no ;   browseable = no ;   create mask = 0600 ;   directory mask = 0700

[printers]    comment = All Printers   browseable = no    path = /var/spool/samba    printable = yes    guest ok = no    read only = yes    create mask = 0700

# Windows clients look for this share name as a source of downloadable
# printer drivers [print$]    comment = Printer Drivers    path = /var/lib/samba/printers    browseable
= yes    read only = yes    guest ok = no
# Uncomment to allow remote administration of Windows print drivers.
# You may need to replace 'lpadmin' with the name of the group your
# admin users are members of.
# Please note that you also need to set appropriate Unix permissions
# to the drivers directory for these users to have write rights in it ;   write list = root, @lpadmin

# A sample share for sharing your CD-ROM with others. ;[cdrom] ;   comment = Samba server's CD-ROM ;   read only = yes ;   locking = no ;   path = /cdrom ;   guest ok = yes

# The next two parameters show how to auto-mount a CD-ROM when the
#   cdrom share is accesed. For this to work /etc/fstab must contain
#   an entry like this:
#
#       /dev/scd0   /cdrom  iso9660 defaults,noauto,ro,user   0 0
#
# The CD-ROM gets unmounted automatically after the connection to the
#
# If you don't want to use auto-mounting/unmounting make sure the CD
#   is mounted on /cdrom
# ;   preexec = /bin/mount /cdrom ;   postexec = /bin/umount /cdrom




[www]   
 browseable = yes   
 writeable = yes
 path = /var/www/    
 force directory mode = 755    
 force create mode = 755    
 valid users = root    
 create mode = 0755    
 directory mode = 0755
```

Comment: VMWare is a company that makes several products. Which product are you using ?

Comment: I'm using vmware player

Answer (score 1):

This will most likely be solved by setting up bridged networking mode on your host between it and the Debian virtual machine.

Comment: Let me give this a go, thx for the advice

Comment: Still not working...

Comment: @Michael: check your firewall settings then.

Comment: @lain iptables are accepting all, no firewall installed, and its on the same physical machine i don't see anything going wrong. Cant seem to figure this one out.

Comment: @Michael: What's the IP address of the server and the guest ?

Comment: non bridged the server was 192.168.0.128, host pc 192.168.0.1